# How to attach click handler to projected content element

Tags: angular, viewchild, ng-template

I'm using content projection to put a button into a component.

```
<hello name="{{ name }}">
  <button #btn>Click Me</button>
</hello>
```

And the component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
  <h3>Hello {{name}}!</h3>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
  `
})
```

So far so good... but i now want to add a (click) event listener to that button and I want the handler to live in the component that receives the projected content.

I was hoping to do the following to access the native element and then add a click listener.

```
@ViewChild('btn') btn
```

Unfortunately, when i console log this.btn in ngAfterViewInit, I get an "undefined". And even if it did work, i figure there must be a more angular way to attach the listener than accessing the native element.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cj4bz1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: Why not `(click)` on the button?

Comment: If I add (click)="onClick()" to the button html  it would try to bind to the component's parent onClick  method

Comment: Why does it need to be bound to the child?

Comment: I want various parents to offer different template customizations for the component. Binding to the child will let me reuse the handler code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `@ContentChild` or `@ContentChildren` which gives you access to projected children inside of your component:

You can read more about it here along with similarities and differences with `@ViewChild` and `@ViewChildren` [Content Child Docs](https://blog.mgechev.com/2016/01/23/angular2-viewchildren-contentchildren-difference-viewproviders/)

After you get access to you Child/Children you can use something like rxjs and the [From Event](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/fromEvent) Operator to get a hold of the click event.

```
fromEvent(this.mycontentchildelement, 'click').subscribe((event) => console.log('got clicked', event));
```

Comment: Can I have an example of this?